# Logon options greyed out for AD FS Service

Tags: adfs

I am trying to change the service account for AD FS service. I go to services.msc and pull up the settings for Active Directory Federation Services. In the Logon tab, the options to change the service account are greyed out.

Is there anything I can do to enable this option to make the change?

Comment: Start the mmc as administrator?

Comment: started it with administrator privileges. no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stopped the Service first?

Her is some more details [Change AD FS 2012 R2 Service Account Password](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2016/12/06/change-ad-fs-2012-r2-service-account-password/)

And there is also a script that can help with the change [Active Directory Federation Services: Change the Service Account](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Active-Directory-ddb67df0#content)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this script:
https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsToolbox/tree/master/serviceAccountModule

```
Install-Module -Name ADFSToolbox -Force
```

**It is highly recommended that you create a backup before attemptig to change the service account as executing cmdlets in the wrong order may result in non-functioning AD FS servers. Performing the change first in a test farm is also advised.**

Althouhgh it is recommended a list of secondary servers be provided when invoking Add-AdfsServiceAccountRule or Remove-AdfsServiceAccountRule on a multi-node WID farm, you can optionally manually force a sync on all secondary servers or allow it to occur on the next sync cycle (5 minutes by default).

Change the service account on each machine in the farm.
Beginning with the secondary servers, run the following:

`Update-AdfsServiceAccount` (summary more commands needed)

Once the function has been executed on all secondary servers, proceed to run it on the primary server.

See also here for the steps:
https://www.reddit.com/r/adfs/comments/n7f2py/service_account_to_gmsa_success/

- Create the gMSA you're going to use, and configure it, including the
  local policy on the 2 ADFS servers (Generate Security Audits, Log On
  As A Service)
- Install Visual C++ on both ADFS servers
- Install ODBC Driver 17 on both servers
- Install SQLCMD on both servers
- Install ActiveDirectory module for Powershell on both servers (Add
  Roles\Features > RSAT > Remote Administrator Tools > AD DS & AD LDS >
  AD for Powershell Module )
- Install ADFS Toolbox on both servers via. Powershell. Make sure PS is
  using TLS 1.2 before trying to install it!
  Import the ADFS Toolbox module on both servers: import-module    adfstoolbox
- Install AdfsServiceAccountModule on both servers: Import-Module
  "C:\Program
  Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ADFSToolbox\2.0.17.0\serviceAccountModule\AdfsServiceAccountModule.psm1"
- On the Primary ADFS server, add the GMSA account:
  add-AdfsServiceAccountRule -ServiceAccount adfs-gmsa$
  -SecondaryServers adfs02.company.com
- On the Secondary server, run: Update-AdfsServiceAccount When
  prompted, set the Operating Mode to #1 - Federation Server
- On the Primary server, run: Update-AdfsServiceAccount When prompted,
  set the Operating Mode to #2 - Final Federation Server
- The script errored out when trying to update the SPN. If necessary,
  delete the old SPN: setspn -D HOST/STS.COMPANY.COM DOMAIN\adfssvc
  Because of #12, I had to generate the new SPN: setspn -S    HOST/STS.COMPANY.COM DOMAIN\ADFS-GMSA$
- Start ADFSSRV service on Primary
- Start ADFSSRV service on Secondary
- Validate that the service is running properly under the new GMSA and
  that replication is occurring (Get-AdfsSyncProperties).
- Remove the old service account information via. the Primary Server:
  remove-AdfsServiceAccountRule -ServiceAccount DOMAIN\adfssvc
  -SecondaryServers adfs02.COMPANY.com
- Cleanup tools and powershell modules.